# Grant file access on google drive by google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a form with script which will access a spreadsheet and write from the form to spreadsheet. My form has file upload function and email to a user the link to access the file on my google drive. Unfortunately, users have to ask for access permission before they can access the file. Is there anyway that I could let users access my file without give the permission manually? Below is my code:

```
  function OnSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var responses = e.response;
  var NameArea = responses.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var PurchaseRequest = responses.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
  var Quantity = responses.getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
  var Quotation = responses.getItemResponses()[3].getResponse();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TKxnfi5LSzznTbjlnqiuSjwvhRmu9Sv1gIiZSDBPlaM');
  var ss = sheet.getSheetByName('2018');
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var NextRow = lastRow+1;
  var SSNameArea, SSPurchaseRequest, SSQuantity,SSQuotation;
  var i = 0;
  var j;
  var PurchaseRequestArr = [];
  var QuantityArr = [];
  var dFile;

  PurchaseRequestArr = PurchaseRequest.split(";");
  QuantityArr = Quantity.split(";");

  var PurchaseRequestArrLength = PurchaseRequestArr.length;
  var PurchaseRequestRow = NextRow + PurchaseRequestArrLength;

  do{
    for (j=NextRow;j<PurchaseRequestRow;j++){
      SSNameArea = ss.getRange(j, 3);
      SSPurchaseRequest = ss.getRange(j, 4);
      SSQuantity = ss.getRange(j, 5);
      SSQuotation = ss.getRange(j, 6);
      SSNameArea.setValue(NameArea);
      SSPurchaseRequest.setValue(PurchaseRequestArr[i]);
      SSQuantity.setValue(QuantityArr[i]);
      //dFile = DriveApp.getFileById(Quotation);
      SSQuotation.setValue("https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + Quotation);
      i++;
      //dFile = DriveApp.getFileById(SSQuotation.setValue(Quotation));
    }
  }
  while(i<PurchaseRequestArrLength);
  MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@gmail.com','subject',"https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + Quotation);

}
```

Comment: Use Drive to share the file with them, by adding them to the file viewers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I ask for a automatically solution, by script if possible. Because whenever User submit form I have to give the access manual everytime.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. You can use (the) Drive (service / API) to change the viewers of a file. Review the Apps Script documentation.

Comment: Do you have detailed documentation along with example. I am new to this and don't know where to start. Thank you.

Comment: As said by @tehhowch, try using Apps Script. Place the code, [`addCommenter(emailAddress)`/`addEditor(emailAddress)`/`addViewer(emailAddress)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) before sending the email. This will automatically give permission to the user depending on the level access you've placed for them.